# Shiny module access output outside namespace

Tags: r, module, namespaces, shiny

I need my Shiny module to hide/show a div outside of the namespace.  I tried passing the div id to the module server function and using shinyjs to show/hide it but that is not working. I'm not getting an error, it just doesn't show/hide the div.

I know the Shiny module documentation says modules cannot access outputs outside the namespace.  The docs do, though, give a way for the module to access inputs outside the namespace using reactives.

Does anyone know if there is a way for a Shiny module to access an output outside the namespace?

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
### ui.R ###
header <- dashboardHeader(
  title = a(href = 'http://google.com')
)

dashboardPage(
  skin = 'black',
  header,

  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu( id='tabs',
             menuItem('Edit Existing Client', tabName = 'client-info')
    )),

  dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs(),
    fluidRow(
      tabItems(
        tabItem(tabName = "client-info",
                div(selectClientModuleUI("clientinfons")),
                div(id='editclientinfo', uiOutput('editclientstuff'))
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

### server.R ###
shinyServer(function(session,input, output) {

  output$editclientstuff <- renderUI({
    div(
      fluidRow(
        column(6,
           textInput('editname', "Display name", value ='Testing name')
        ),
        column(6,
               numericInput('editastart','Start', value ='3') 
        )
      )
    )
  })


  callModule(selectClientModule, 'clientinfons', 'editclientinfo')
  shinyjs::hide(id='editclientstuff')
})

### in global.R ###
selectClientModuleUI <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)

  clientlist = c(0, 1, 2)
  names(clientlist) = c('Choose client', 'Fred', 'Kim')

  div( 
    selectInput(ns('selectclient'), 'Select client to edit', choices = clientlist, selected = NULL, multiple = FALSE)
  )
}

selectClientModule <- function(input, output, session, divtoshow = ''){
  observeEvent(input$selectclient, {
    if (!is.null(input$selectclient) && input$selectclient > 0){
      print(paste0("showing ", divtoshow))
      shinyjs::show(divtoshow)
    }
  })

}
```

Answer (score 2):

That is possible by giving the value as a reactive (not as the value of the reactive) to the module. You can change the reactive Value in the module and return the reactive from the Module to the app (note, return the reactive itself, not its value). The following app switches the 'divtoshow' in the main app from inside the module. If nothing is selected, it's hidden, otherwise it's shown (note, I adjusted you code a little so it's working as a stand-alone app):

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)


# Module
selectClientModuleUI <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)

  clientlist = c(0, 1, 2)
  names(clientlist) = c('Choose client', 'Fred', 'Kim')

  div( 
    selectInput(ns('selectclient'), 'Select client to edit', choices = clientlist, selected = NULL, multiple = FALSE)
  )
}

selectClientModule <- function(input, output, session, divtoshow){

  observeEvent(input$selectclient, {
    if (input$selectclient > 0){
      print(paste0("showing editclientinfo"))

      divtoshow("editclientinfo") # set the div to show to "editclientinfo", this will be visible outside the module
    }else{
      divtoshow("") # set the div to show to "", if nothing was chosen
    }
  })

    # return the div to show as reactive to the main app
    return(divtoshow)
}


# Main App
ui <- shinyUI(
  dashboardPage(
    skin = 'black',
    dashboardHeader(
      title = a(href = 'http://google.com')
    ),
    dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu( id='tabs',
                   menuItem('Edit Existing Client', tabName = 'client-info')
      )),

    dashboardBody(
      useShinyjs(),
      fluidRow(
        tabItems(
          tabItem(tabName = "client-info",
                  div(selectClientModuleUI("clientinfons")),
                  div(id='editclientinfo', uiOutput('editclientstuff'))
          )
        )
      )
    )
  ))

server <- shinyServer(function(session,input, output) {

  output$editclientstuff <- renderUI({
    div(
      fluidRow(
        column(6,
               textInput('editname', "Display name", value ='Testing name')
        ),
        column(6,
               numericInput('editastart','Start', value ='3') 
        )
      )
    )
  })

    # store the div to show in a reactive
    divtoshow <- reactiveVal('')

    # divtoshow can be changed in side this module, so it's a return value
    divtoshow <- callModule(selectClientModule, 'clientinfons', divtoshow)

    # observe the value of divtoshow and toggle the corresponding div
    observeEvent(divtoshow(), {
      if(divtoshow() == "editclientinfo"){
        shinyjs::show("editclientinfo")
      }else{
        shinyjs::hide("editclientinfo")
      }

    })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: nice answer. I am breaking a big code into modules. Wondering Is it possible to have the dropdown inputs and conditional panels in the  sidebarpanel and the outbput on the dashboardbody? All the example I came across have both the inputs and the plots/table output in the body. Is there any example you can direct me to ?

Comment: Just by putting all the necessary elements into the sidebar.

Comment: I am unclear how the code works. What is the variable `divtoshow`? It seems a reactive variable but is undeclared yet. This is an important question effectively documenting: _how to show/hide divs from inside a shiny module._ Could someone from rstudio point me to any documentation that explains this concept in detail?

Comment: It is declared in the server as reactiveVal: divtoshow <- reactiveVal(''). The reactive is then given into the module with callModule which has a return value, thus divtoshow is updated. Google how to use Shiny modules for the general mechanics.